# How to make a synchronous GET request

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I have a method for GET request in my code:

```
  func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject], completionHandler: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionTask {

    let parameterString = parameters.stringFromHttpParameters()
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"\(path)?\(parameterString)")!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer " + userInfoDefaults.stringForKey("accessToken")!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:completionHandler)
    task.resume()

    return task
  }
```

That is called by an another method that populates a picker view on a specific scene:

```
  func getAffiliateds() -> [String]? {
    var affiliateds:[String] = []
    makeHTTPGetRequest(baseURL + "affiliateds", parameters: [:], completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
      do {
        affiliateds = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [String]
        print (affiliateds)
      }
      catch { print("Error: \(error)") }
    })
    return affiliateds
  }
```

I need to get all affiliateds from my webservice and then list it on the picker view. But when I debugged the code I noticed that affiliateds are first returned as a null array and then it is returned with the correct information. I need to return the array from getAffiliateds only when it has already received the data from the webservice. How can I make this?

Comment: Asynchronous code cannot be called synchronously.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't understand. I've just started with Swift programming about a month ago. Could you suggest me what I need to change on my code to make the request asynchronous?

Comment: @Charles - The `getAffiliateds` shouldn't try to return the data. Move the code that populates the picklist _into_ the `completionHandler` in `getAffiliateds` (or repeat the `completionHandler` pattern, and have the routine that calls `getAffiliateds` do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Your `getAffiliateds()` *cannot* return a value dependent on the asynchronous code that it will run. That is the nature of asynchronous code. Instead, perform a callback of some sort *in the completion handler* when it is called:

```
makeHTTPGetRequest(baseURL + "affiliateds", parameters: [:], completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
  do {
    affiliateds = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [String]
    print (affiliateds)
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
}
```

A frequent strategy is for the caller to provide *another* completion handler which *this* completion handler will call.

Comment: And please do a search, as this has been discussed and explained fully innumerable times on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 1):

You have a routine:

```
func getAffiliateds() -> [String]? {
    var affiliateds:[String] = []
    makeHTTPGetRequest(baseURL + "affiliateds", parameters: [:], completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            affiliateds = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [String]
            print (affiliateds)
        }
        catch { print("Error: \(error)") }
    })
    return affiliateds
}
```

And you presumably have some code that does something like:

```
func populatePicklist() {
    let affiliateds = getAffiliateds()
    // populate picklist here
}
```

You should change this to:

```
func getAffiliatedsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ([String]?) -> ()) {
    makeHTTPGetRequest(baseURL + "affiliateds", parameters: [:]) { data, response, error in
        do {
            let affiliateds = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [String]  // two notes here: first, define local var here, not up above; second, use `as?` to gracefully handle problems where result was not `[String]`
            print (affiliateds)
            completionHandler(affiliateds)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}

func populatePicklist() {
    getAffiliatedsWithCompletionHandler { affiliateds in
        // populate picklist here
    }

    // but not here
}
```